# cookie can't expire after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies, setcookie

I have created a cookie and want it to expire after 10seconds. However, it doesn't work. I have tried to close the browser but the data still here.

This is the code I set for the cookie.

```
setcookie('attempt','', time()+10);
```

Comment: And what's setcookie function from? It's not a web standard so it would help if you explained that

Comment: @DominicTobias http://php.net/setcookie ?

Comment: Use `.localStorage` for this, not cookies.

Comment: Aha right, I was thinking over clientside land!

Comment: What is the return value of the setcookie() function? Might help to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have no idea where and how your `setcookie()` method is called, but it is server side in each case. So when you reload the site after closing the browser, the script is executed again and so the cookie is also sent again.

http://php.net/setcookie

You can also set cookies on the client side (which i'd prefer):

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it still can't work. Actually, everything is alright to use the cookie but the problem is can't expire.

Comment: I am doing a game that only can play three times per day. After each game, "1" will plus to the cookie. After all the attempts are used, user can't start any new game. When user login, a cookie will be set in order to record the attempt and will expire after 24 hours. Since I am testing, so I set it to be 10 seconds.

Comment: `Actually, everything is alright to use the cookie but the problem is can't expire` - have you tried setting the cookie at the client side?

Comment: I find out the problem. I make a very silly and stupid mistake...... I forgot to set the expire when I update the cookie. Really speechless to myself. But really thanks for your help!!!!